# Unable to decrease wait time between messages in Azure service bus SDK using java

Tags: java, azure

I am migrating to the newer SDK for azure service bus.
When the 1st message is read , it simply waits for a fixed 1 minute to pick up the next message.
I am unable to change this behaviour either by setting maxTimeOut in ServiceBusReceiverClient.java or by setting AmqpRetryOptions.

Any pointers to solve this would be really appreciated.
i dont want to wait for 1 minute because we need to process millions of messages everyday.
My processing is over in a few milliseconds.

I just need to read 100 or more messages and write them to kafka topic, then flush kafka..

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
        <version>7.15.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my code.

```
AmqpRetryOptions retryOptions = new AmqpRetryOptions();
retryOptions.setTryTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
retryOptions.setDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(10));


ServiceBusReceiverClient receiver = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
    .retryOptions(retryOptions)
    .connectionString(connectionStr)
    .receiver().maxAutoLockRenewDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(lockDuration))
    .prefetchCount(properties.getNumMsgs())
    .topicName(azure.getServicebusTopicName())
    .subscriptionName(azure.getSubscriptionName())
    .buildClient();

receiver.close();
kafkaProd.flushKafka();
```

Answer (score 0):

> i dont want to wait for 1 minute because we need to process millions of messages everyday. My processing is over in a few milliseconds.

- ***Here, we can utilize Azure Service Bus's ability to receive messages in batches asynchronously. By doing so, you can continuously receive messages and process them rapidly.***

**ServiceBusToKafkaMigration :**

```java
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ServiceBusToKafkaMigration {

    private static final String connectionString = "<Your-Service-Bus-Connection-String>";
    private static final String topicName = "<Your-Service-Bus-Topic-Name>";
    private static final String kafkaBootstrapServers = "<Your-Kafka-Bootstrap-Servers>";
    private static final String kafkaTopic = "<Your-Kafka-Topic>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Service Bus Receiver
        ServiceBusReceiverClient receiverClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .receiver()
                .topicName(topicName)
                .buildClient();

        // Create Kafka Producer
        Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
        kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(kafkaProps);

        // Continuously receive messages from Service Bus and write to Kafka
        while (true) {
            receiverClient.receiveMessages(100).forEach(message -> {
                kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(kafkaTopic, message.getBody().toString()),
                        (recordMetadata, exception) -> {
                            if (exception != null) {
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Message sent to Kafka topic: " + recordMetadata.topic());
                            }
                        });
            });

            // Flush Kafka Producer after each batch
            kafkaProducer.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

- We continuously receive messages from Azure Service Bus in batches of 100 using the `receiveMessages(100)` method.
- Each batch of messages is then asynchronously sent to the Kafka topic.
- The Kafka producer is flushed after each batch to ensure messages are sent promptly.

[image]